# Unable to drag and drop element for AngularJS application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am trying to drag and drop elements on a AngularJS demo site, but I am not able to achieve results.

For my practice I am using https://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested , and I am trying to drag & drop 'Item 7 (From dropzone B)' to 'Item 3 (In container 1)'.

I have used `.getText()` method to ensure that my `xpath` is pointing to the correct element. But still it is not working. Below is my code:

```
public void SetUp() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    d = new ChromeDriver();
    d.manage().window().maximize();
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    d.get("https://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    ((JavascriptExecutor)d).executeScript("scroll(4,400)");
    WebElement src = d.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/div"));
    System.out.println("The src element is:" +src.getText());
    WebElement destn = d.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li/div"));
    System.out.println("The src element is:" +destn.getText());
    org.openqa.selenium.Point pt1 = src.getLocation();
    org.openqa.selenium.Point pt2 = destn.getLocation();
    int xCord1 = pt1.getX();
    int yCord1 = pt1.getY();
    int xCord2 = pt2.getX();
    int yCord2 = pt2.getY();
    System.out.println("The X & Y cordinate of the src is:" +xCord1+ " & " +yCord1);
    System.out.println("The X & Y cordinate of the destn is:" +xCord2+ " & " +yCord2);
    Actions ac = new Actions(d);
    Action dragAndDrop = ac.clickAndHold(src).moveToElement(destn, 334, 661).release(destn).build();
    dragAndDrop.perform();

}
```

Comment: Could you be missing the Actions.Build() for Actions act?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake..But I have commented this line (Actions act = new Actions(d)) in my original code, because I have already created 'ac' object for Actions class.